# My code removed all punctuation from text but do we need few of them for sentimental analysis?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, sentiment-analysis

```
def remove_punctuation(review):
    lst = []
    for text in review:
        if text not in string.punctuation:
            lst.append(text)
    return "".join(lst)
df.Review = df.Review.apply(lambda x: remove_punctuation(x))
```

I am working on the sentimental analysis of amazon product reviews. I am preprocessing the reviews' text and used the above function to remove punctuation. It has removed all of them, but my question is that do we consider some of them for sentimental analysis. Like !. Is it the right approach.

**Thanks for your help and time.**

Comment: Great question! I've often wondered this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no clear answer for this. Most nlp tasks require some form of text-preprocessing for the models to better infer on texts. However, in case of sentiment analysis, punctuation such as `!` might be valuable as it indiciates emphasis on text:

`I lost my purse!!` might have a more negative connotation than `Well, I lost my purse.`

You have two ways to approach this problem:

1. You could only exclude functional punctuation like `,.;` etc. and leave in the `!` and the `?` kind of punctuation. Then look at the performance of your sentiment analysis model.
2. Evaluate your model both before and after cleaning all punctuation. You can write some kind of grid-search functionality that would control which punctuation to remove and which not and compare the performance.

All in all, as in most machine learning problems (I assume you do sentiment analysis by using a trained model) it comes down to a particular dataset and model whether the interpunction interferes with the model's performance or not. If, however, you use some form of third party API for the analysis, you can safely let the punctuation as it is, as the third-party API will most likely handle the cleaning themselves.

Hope that this gave some intuition!